# AlamofireObjectMapper issues after xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm using AlamofireObjectMapper in my project which uses Swift 2.3. After updating my xcode to version 8 my project won't compile anymore, showing the following issues:

[image: AlamofireObjectMapper issues]

I set the "Use Legacy swift Language version" to YES in the project build settings.

This is a part of my podfile:

```
def default_pods
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 3.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Cocoapods to v1.1.0, remove the post install hook from your podfile, and run `pod update`.  You may also need to remove the '~> 3.0' version attribute from the pod.

Comment: This worked perfectly, also if anyone experiences issues with their libraries they should check if that library has a new branch for swift 2.3 and swift 3.0 support (E.g. for Swift Reachability: pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 2.4' .. according to their documentation)